# Python AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'verify_mode'

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a connection using ssl._create_unverified_context as context:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com', context=ssl._create_unverified_context)
conn.request()
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
conn.close()
```

what I get is this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-c21b1071d0e6> in <module>
----> 1 conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com', context=ssl._create_unverified_context)
      2 conn.request()
      3 res = conn.getresponse()
      4 data = res.read()
      5 conn.close()

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py in __init__(self, host, port, key_file, cert_file, timeout, source_address, context, check_hostname, blocksize)
   1396                 if context.post_handshake_auth is not None:
   1397                     context.post_handshake_auth = True
-> 1398             will_verify = context.verify_mode != ssl.CERT_NONE
   1399             if check_hostname is None:
   1400                 check_hostname = context.check_hostname

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'verify_mode'
```

Comment: I think it should be `context=ssl._create_unverified_context()`

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve using this code, but maybe you want to have a look at the requests package: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet works fine for me:

```
import http.client
import ssl
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com', context=ssl._create_unverified_context)
```